Testing application that uses shared database tables
How should I approach integration testing code in an application that for some functionality queries database tables that are also used by other application I do not have source code for?

You only test your code, not someone's else. As long as you can build the proper DB schema, you just test normally, the fact that some other code queries it is irrelevant for your testing.

I think you have misunderstood the question. My application is using shared tables from database that is used by/built for some other application. I do not own that other application.

Cristal clear. As long as you can replicate the DB schema from the tables you query, it should suffice to build tests on that. You just need scripts to create the DB from scratch, which you can even make them from your code or extract creation scripts from a live database.

@Alejandro is this standard approach when it comes to this kind of testing? Or is it preferred to build API that encapsulates logic for other application and just mock calls to API assuming that the API functionality is correct?

No idea if there is even a "standard". An API built by yourself will just move the problem somewhere else, for testing the main system you mock the API, then you need to test the API itself, which has the same DB problem as before. But if such an API is provided by the other system, testing it is not your responsability, your only test will be to assert the correct calls are made and testinng your behavior from certain responses, you mock it away and forget there is a shared DB (since you no longer touch it directly).
